# Cannot implement pinia store in own keycloak plugin vue3

Tags: vuejs3, keycloak, pinia

an App in vue3 + vite + pinia + keycloak

in main.ts

```
app.use(pinia)
app.use(router)
app.use(auth)
app.use(vuetify)
app.mount("#app")
```

but in my keycloak after init I try to use pinia store

```
  **const userStore = useUserStore()**

  try {
    const authenticated = await keycloak.init(KCInitOptions)

    if (authenticated) {
      const tokenParsed: TokenParsed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(keycloak.tokenParsed))
      userStore.setUserAuthStatus(authenticated)
      const user: User = {
        id: tokenParsed.sub || "",
        name: tokenParsed.name || "",
        email: tokenParsed.email || "",
        access_token: keycloak.token || "",
        refresh_token: keycloak.refreshToken || "",
      }

      **userStore.setUser(user)**
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }

  return {
    install: (app: App) => {
      app.provide("Auth", Auth)
    },
  }
}
```

but this results in error

[image]

I followed on https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html#single-page-applications and coud implement that on vue router but not inside keycloak

How enable pinia in own Plugin?

Comment: Did you get this working? Or do you have a full reproducible example? (Is "keycloak" a vue component, or keycloak.ts? I'm wondering if main.ts has been read and processed before keycloak is? If not, that would give the error.)

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74687661/841830 ?

Comment: @DarrenCook I can not run it in any plugin. Therefore I made a workaround, s. here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lc4HiC8G1MJGKKejTInD781eDtTw9jrgLdDiRMzVVS8/edit