# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tokenParsed') with Vue3 and Keycloak

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, keycloak

I'am using Keycloak in my vue-app to handle authentication. The app is  built up with some components like header, some pages in main view and footer. If I run the app and I get logged in I get redirected to a blank screen and on console I see error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tokenParsed')
    at Proxy.getName (TheHeader.vue?ad06:85:1)
    at eval (TheHeader.vue?ad06:16:1)
    at renderFnWithContext (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:852:1)
    at normalizeChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:7006:1)
    at createBaseVNode (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6755:1)
    at _createVNode (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6857:1)
    at createVNodeWithArgsTransform (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6712:1)
    at eval (TheHeader.vue?ad06:13:1)
    at renderFnWithContext (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:852:1)
    at normalizeChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:7006:1)
```

As you can see the error is located in the header component and there in the `getName()` function.

```
  methods: {
    logout () {
      app.$keycloak.logout({ redirectUri: window.location.origin })
    },
    getName(){
      const fristname = app.$keycloak.tokenParsed.first_name
```

If I use console.log to see value of app it returns:
`<div id="app"></div>`

I think the problem is that the data of the keycloak initialization is not transfered to the header component. But why? Keycloak is initialized in main.js like this:

```
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(authPlugin)
app.use(VueLogger)

/**
 * @login-required: authentication of client if user is logged in, or displaying login page if not.
 */
app.$keycloak
  .init({ onLoad: 'login-required', checkLoginIframe: false })
  .then(() => {
    app.use(vuetify)
    app.use(router)
    app.use(store)
    console.log(app)
  }).catch(() => {
    console.log("failed to initialize keycloak.")
  })
  app.mount('#app')
```

As I can see on console too, the app object is initialized with the data of the Keycloak instance.

To find a solution, I tried to import the initialized `app` object into the header component. But this did not work. Also removing the `app` object ends in the error message that `$keycloak` was not found.

It's my first Vue project, so any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not experienced with Vue but I have a similar issue with Angular (very similar).

I think that's because Keycloak service is not initialized yet in the component you're calling it in.

My issue is, the Keycloak service does not get initialized in the app.component (parent component in the application). So when I call KeycloakService, it will throw undefined.

A "workaround" would be to find a component that comes later in the lifecycle of your application, and use Keycloak service there.

Comment: I found the error myself. Just remove the 'app'- calls like `app.$keycloak.tokenParsed.first_name` and replace it with the `this`. After that I got no error message